# Retrieving a BLOB type into Byte

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ImageModel ImageModel = new ImageModel();

> So here is my snippet

```
    Cursor Cursor = DB.rawQuery("SELECT ImageFile FROM Image WHERE ID = '1'", null);

    if(Cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        System.out.println("NO DATA");
    }else {
        System.out.println("HAVE DATA");
        byte[] byteArray = Cursor.getBlob(1);
        ImageModel.setImage(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length));
    }
```

> I got an error from this code 
>           `byte[] byteArray = Cursor.getBlob(1);`

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Comment: ImageFile in my table has BLOB data type

Comment: `byte[] byteArray = Cursor.getBlob(0);` the index is 0 based.

Comment: i changed my getBlob(1) to 0, it also have the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `moveToFirst()` so the index of the `Cursor` is positioned to the 1st row (if it exists) and instead of `1` use `0` as the index in `getBlob()` because column indices are `0` based:

```
Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("SELECT ImageFile FROM Image WHERE ID = '1'", null);

if(!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    System.out.println("NO DATA");
} else {
    System.out.println("HAVE DATA");
    byte[] byteArray = cursor.getBlob(1);
    ImageModel.setImage(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length));
}
```